# ROBLOX - Trying to get my desired effect?

Tags: lua, roblox

sorry about the vague title, I have no idea on how to explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to replicate a "choosing"(?) effect from a ROBLOX game [shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5G7bOEEp-xU&user=badfitz66)

I've gotten to basically the exact same thing, except for one problem. It always stops on the same part every time (the top). Posting here is my current last resort (the scripting subforum on roblox is incredibly inactive)

```
for i = 1, 3 do
    for _, ll in pairs(P:GetChildren()) do
        lastbcolor = ll.BrickColor
        ll.BrickColor = BrickColor.Yellow()
        wait(t)
        ll.BrickColor = lastbcolor
        lastpicked = ll
        print(t)
        t=t+0.2 -- to slow down
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local t = P:GetChildren()
local N = #t                  -- number of menu items
local K = 1
for R = 20 + math.random(N), 1, -1 do
  ll = t[K]
  local lastbcolor = ll.BrickColor
  ll.BrickColor = BrickColor.Yellow()
  wait( R^-.7*.7 )
  ll.BrickColor = lastbcolor
  K = K % N + 1
end
ll = t[K]
-- blink 
for R = 1, 5 do
  local lastbcolor = ll.BrickColor
  ll.BrickColor = BrickColor.Yellow()
  wait( .3 )
  ll.BrickColor = lastbcolor
  wait( .3 )
end
```